# Why isn't the return function inside my recursive call being executed?

Tags: python, binary-tree

Thanks for the corrections, I have made the amendments, but there is still one issue I can't get over:

```
class Solution:
    def hasPathSum(self, root: TreeNode, targetSum: int) -> bool:
        if not root:
            return False

        if not root.left and not root.right:
            if root.val ==targetSum:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        remainingSum = targetSum - root.val

        def dfs(remainingSum, root):
            dfs(remainingSum - root.left.val, root.left)
            dfs(remainingSum - root.right.val, root.right)

            if remainingSum == 0:
                return True

        return dfs(remainingSum, root)
```

From within the recursive function, what do I return? Or is the code above correct now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you are right about the two `return` statements:

```python
        return dfs(remainingSum,root)
        
        return False
```

There is no way that second `return` statement could ever be executed. So let's look at the rest of the program. First, what should the logic be?

1. First, `hasPathSum` on entry checks to see if `root` evaluates to `True` and if not it return `False`. This is good.
2. It should then check to see if the root node's value is equal to the passed `targetSum` value because if it is, we can immediately return `True`. But instead your program is immediately subtracting the root node's value from `targetSum` yielding `remainingSum` and you never check for `targetSum`. So imagine a tree that consisted of only a root with no leaves whose value was `5` and we called `hasPathSum` with `targetSum` set to 5. We should be returning `True`. Remember: *A **leaf** is a node with no children.* Thus the root of this tree is also a leaf and should be checked.
3. Otherwise, recursively call `hasPathSum` on the left tree of the current node passing `remainingSum`. If the return value is `True`, then return `True`. (There is no need to first check to see if the left tree value exists with `if root.left:` because when you call `hasPathSum` recursively it is already checking `if not root:`)
4. Otherwise return the value you receive from calling `hasPathSum` on the right tree passing `remainingSum`.
5. There is no need for a separate `dfs` function.

If you just use the `TreeNode` constructor for creating and initializing tree nodes, then you will be creating your nodes "bottom up", i.e. leaves before their parents. For example:

```python
node_1 = TreeNode(7)
node_2 = TreeNode(8)
node_3 = TreeNode(9, left=node_1, right=node_2)
node_4 = TreeNode(4, left=node_3)
node_5 = TreeNode(2, right=node_4)
node_6 = TreeNode(14)
root = TreeNode(6, left=node_5, right=node_6)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not return twice in a function.You should return the result of `dfs`.
2. Your `dfs` function with a wrong exit condition, you need check the `remainingSum` before run into next dfs.
3. When you find a leaf, you need to check the `remainingSum`, rather than `return None`.

code:

```
    def hasPathSum(self, root: TreeNode, targetSum: int) -> bool:
        def dfs(remainingSum,root): 
            if not root.left and not root.right:
                if remainingSum == 0: 
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            if root.left: 
                x = dfs(remainingSum-root.left.val, root.left)
            else:
                x = False
            if root.right: 
                y = dfs(remainingSum-root.right.val, root.right)
            else:
                y = False
            return x or y

        if not root: 
            return False
        return dfs(targetSum - root.val,root)
```

result:

```
Runtime: 40 ms, faster than 83.76% of Python3 online submissions for Path Sum.
Memory Usage: 16 MB, less than 18.57% of Python3 online submissions for Path Sum.
```